Avoid tab splitting in VSCode
VSCode (Ubuntu) automatically splits the editor tab. How disable this?


See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_sticky-scroll

Does this answer your question? How to remove that tree structure at the top on Visual Studio?
